# Mapping value of an array as parameter to a function PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, mapping

So I have a function:

```
$v->firstOrCreate([
    "test_page" => $vessel["test_page"],
    "deck" => $vessel->deck,
    "test_order" => $vessel->test_order,
    "component_name" => $vessel->component_name,
]);
```

And this code is repetitive but with different set of fields. So I try to reduce the code by a helper function: this will take an array of field and pass it as parameter to a function but also do some kind of mapping value inside that function. I know it is kinda confusing to describe and I am not sure if this is a thing.
Is there any way in PHP I can do something like

```
$field = ["field1","field2","field3","field4","field5",]
$model->firstOrCreate(
    foreach ($field as $i) {
        $i => $data[$i];
    }
);
```

Thanks !

Comment: **Is there any way in PHP I can do something like** why didn't try it for your self

Comment: So, essentially you want to iterate through your array and call a function on each element, right? You also want to consolidate this to one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$data` has the same fields as `$fields` just do:

```
Model::firstOrCreate($data);
```

If you must use your loop to extract a few fields do it before the function call:

```
$fields = ["field1","field2","field3","field4","field5",]
$attributes = [];
foreach ($fields as $field) {
   $attributes[$field] = $data[$field];
}
$model->firstOrCreate($attributes);
```